# Is it possible to to target Amazon Appstore devices in the Android manifest to have different hardware permissions than Google Play devices?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions, amazon-appstore

Is it possible to to target Amazon Appstore devices in the Android manifest to have different hardware permissions than Google Play devices? In the example below only Amazon devices would have request the permission to SEND_SMS.

For example:

```
<Amazon-sdk>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<Amazon-sdk>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Create an `amazon` [product flavor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors) and a `google` product flavor

Step #2: In `app/src/amazon/AndroidManifest.xml`, have your `<uses-permission>` element(s) that you only want for the Amazon Appstore, and (presumably) only have the code that uses that permission in the `amazon` source set as well

Step #3: Upload the `amazon` build to the Amazon Appstore, and upload the `google` build to the Play Store